# Unable to connect to Mongo Using VertxMongo clinent

Tags: mongodb, ssl, vert.x

Hi enables ssl in mongo server and trying to connect from vertx MongoClient.
Step followed : **"ssl":true** in configuration and set **System.setProperty("org.mongodb.async.type", "netty")** before intializing the clinet. When I try running my vertx application i am getting following error. can some one please help?

```
com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary}. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=testssl@cv.com:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message}, caused by {javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSLEngine closed already}}]
    at com.mongodb.connection.BaseCluster.createTimeoutException(BaseCluster.java:377)
    at com.mongodb.connection.BaseCluster.handleServerSelectionRequest(BaseCluster.java:292)
    at com.mongodb.connection.BaseCluster.access$800(BaseCluster.java:54)
    at com.mongodb.connection.BaseCluster$WaitQueueHandler.run(BaseCluster.java:458)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```